# Services menu shows the incorrect name

Tags: macos, automator, services

I made a Service in Automator, but when I was saving mistyped the name. I used Automator to rename the Service, but the incorrect name shows up in my Services menu.

I checked the `~/Library/Services` directory and the name is correct and the file metadata shows the correct name.

Why does the Services menu show the old name and how do I fix it?

Comment: restart you computer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have rebooted!

Comment: how do I suppose to know that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the Launch Services database.

Open the Terminal and run the following command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, you can open up the service in AppleScript Editor and correct the name/spelling just by deleting and retyping.